# Let $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ Suppose $g(0) < g(1)$ and for each x in $\mathbb{R}$ the set $g^{-1}(x)$ consists of at most one element

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ Suppose $g(0) < g(1)$ and for each x in $\mathbb{R}$ the set  $g^{-1}(x)$  consists of at most one element. Prove that $g$ is strictly increasing.

I would appreciate any help, as I do not know where to start.

Comment: $g(x)=x$ for $x\neq1/3,2/3$ and $g(1/3)=2/3$ and $g(2/3)=1/3$

Comment: Is $g$ continuous? If not I think $g(0)= 0, g(1) = 1,$ and $g(x) = 1-x$ for $x \in (0,1)$ satisfies the hypotheses but is not strictly increasing.

Comment: @copper.hat..its not given that f is continuous

Comment: @suresh Then the example given by treeleaf is a clear counterexample.  I mean, you know nothing about $g$ other than the fact that it's one-one onto it's range and the comparison between two arbitrary values. This is barely any information. I can construct a function which violates strict increases between infinitely many points and yet satisfies this criteria.

Comment: I guess continuous is the weakest property that this statement holds.  (among elementary conditions on functions)

Comment: @ElfHog Would semicontinuity (I think upper) also suffice?

Comment: Try $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{when }0\leq x<\frac{1}{4}\\
x+\frac{1}{4}&\text{when }\frac{1}{4}\leq x\leq\frac{1}{2}\\
x-\frac{1}{4}&\text{when }\frac{1}{2}<x<\frac{3}{4}\\
0.99x+0.01&\text{when }\frac{3}{4}\leq x\leq 1\end{cases}$$
Sorry I struggle to make it really work but I mean just have it separated into few parts, with each part continuous, and with good jump-condition.

Comment: First of all, your conditions contradict each other, for if $g$ is indeed an invertible function, then its inverse must be injective.